# Access User fields using UserProfile object

Tags: django, django-models, django-views

I want to access User model fields using UserProfile object.
I have a 'role' field in Userprofile,

```
class UserProfile(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User)
    role = models.CharField(max_length=30)
```

Each user has a role, 'supervisor' or 'admin' now I want to get the user objects whose role=supervisor. I want to be able to access the username of those users with role supervisor which is in User model customized.
I cant get the query right. Help please.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
supervisor_usernames = [up.user.username for up in UserProfile.objects.filter(
    role='supervisor')]
```